# how to pass this postman script test?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

```
pm.test('get single collection', () => {
    pm.expect(error).to.equal(null);
    pm.expect(response).to.have.property('code', 200);
    pm.expect(response).to.have.property('status', 'OK');
    pm.expect(response.json().collection.auth.type, 'check collection authorization').to.equal("apikey")
```

> get single workspace | AssertionError: expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code' of 200, but got 401
>
> get single collection | AssertionError: expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code' of 200, but got 401
>
> get single environment | AssertionError: expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code' of 200, but got 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
You need to send Authorization details from the Authorization tab which you can see in the image below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to ensure that your API request being properly authenticated so you get a `200` response and not `401` which means you are unauthorized to make the request.

This is the assertion that is failing because it's expecting the response code to be 200 - successful but based on your errors, you are getting 401 - unauthorized

```
 pm.expect(response).to.have.property('code', 200);
```

If you successfully authenticate your request your test should pass after.

---

[Learn more about the response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)